# Prefix and Suffix issue (second part)

Tags: suffixes, prefixes

I'm developing an application in English language but my English is not very good.

The application consists in to load a text file, specify a prefix and a suffix, then when the file is loaded and the prefix/suffix are set, the user needs to click in a button to prefix and suffix all the lines of the textfile.

The problem is I don't know how to name the button to perform the action of Prefix and Suffix the text.

To understand it better, if I have an application which cuts some text, then the button name to perform the action would be "***Cut the text***", if I have an application to copy some text, the button name would be "**Copy the text**"

In this case I don't know which is the correct verb to Prefix and Suffix, maybe the correct verb would be "***Affix the text***"?

I'm from Spain. In Spanish there exist a verb to Prefix, but I think doesn't exist any verb to Suffix a word, and neither to Prefix and Suffix at the same time, but maybe I'm wrong.

> UPDATE:

Screenshot to understand the scenario

[image]

Full resolution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI2ri.png

Comment: To make sure we understand: Your program reads in a file and adds a prefix and suffix to each line, like this? `line1 line2 line3`->`aaline1zz aaline2zz aaline3zz`

Comment: *Affix* is used with *to*: "affix A to B". Since you're dealing with three texts - the source, the prefix and the suffix - I suggest ***Concatenate texts***. If you think that will not be familiar to your audience, then ***Join texts*** is a simpler alternative.

Comment: As a programmer, the UI best choice is probably not to have the button you're talking about; it sounds like your UI is more difficult to understand than necessary.

Comment: @Chrylis you understanded good. And the UI needs to be friendly to the user to perform actions using buttons instead perform actions automatically in execution time.

Comment: You should be using i18n features anyway (like `ResourceBundle` in Java), which means you can replace the text after everything else is ready. @StoneyB, for a case like this, would it be appropriate to include a screenshot with the question?

Comment: @chrylis Wouldn't hurt. But it looks to me like this is basically just a "commit" button, only OP wants to label it in such a way that it's unambiguous what is being committed to.

Comment: @StoneyB Right, but it's unclear at what stage this is being applied, and whether additional alternatives are being offered; e.g., "prepend" and "append" are related likely candidates.

Comment: Guys give me a moment and I will upload a screenshot, I need to translate all the words, EDIT: Uploaded!

Comment: Oh, in this case, you're better off using text that describes the intent of what's happening. I suggest "Mark answers" (also "Question/Answer delimiter", and note with a border or a change in text that the prefix/suffix are for the *correct* answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "Build answer sheet" or "Assemble answer sheet" or "Format answer sheet"
or "Insert markers".

Also you have misspelled 'containing' in two places.